# Touchscreen keyboard cuts off at bottom of screen

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, touchscreen

I'm having an issue with the Ubuntu touchscreen keyboard. Whenever I tap somewhere I can type the keyboard opens but cuts off at the bottom of the screen. See attached picture. How can I make the entire keyboard show? Version is 18.04 LTS.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: In the bottom right corner there is a button that will bring up a preferences button on the left. though you cannot see it probably with your problem.  there is a gnome tweak extension called  improve onscreen keyboard that gives you an icon in top bar, and left clicking on that will give you the preferences. you can experiment with showing it at bottom or top etc.                                                                  https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1631/improve-onscreen-keyboard/

Comment: I tried this extension but it crashed and completely killed the on screen keyboard. Trying to get it running again. I did find a bug report that may be related to my issue: https://github.com/pop-os/gnome-shell-theme/issues/34 Will the extension let me change the font size?

Comment: preferences, themes, customise theme will get key size, which is same as font.